# Is it possible to get a singleton view model in mvvmCross?

Tags: singleton, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I have a view which has 2 controls on it.  They all use the same viewmodel, but if controlA makes a change to the view model, then I want controlB and the view to be able to see the change that has been made.  My first thought about how to do this is to make the viewmodel a singleton, but I can't work out how to do this.  Any suggestions either for making the view model a singleton or for a different way to achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#overriding-viewmodel-locationconstruction

Comment: link is broken @Stuart

Comment: updated link https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customizing-using-App-and-Setup#overriding-viewmodel-locationconstruction